# textAngular pasting in IE not working

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm using [textAngular](http://www.textangular.com/) as a WYSIWYG text editor in an angular app. It is a fantastic library that is essentially plug and play. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

The problem is when I attempt to paste some text into the textAngular window in IE it simply doesn't work. It doesn't raise any console events, throw any exceptions or anything. On the network, it calls 4 URLs, which are then all aborted. They are:

- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
- http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300
- http://www.textangular.com/css/style.css

This network activity does *not* happen in Chrome and Firefox. So, I think that is where the problem is. But for the life of me I can't figure out what is going on. It doesn't look like this problem has been reported to the textAngular team or has been asked on stack overflow.

Does anyone have an I idea of how I can remedy the situation?

Edit:

Here is a [plunk](http://tinyurl.com/nlz4jps) replicating the situation. It is the demo from the github repo, almost verbatim (the link to the textAngular links were dead, and I got ride of the initial text). I'm pretty sure that it is just a problem within the 1.2.2 library and I'm going to report a bug. The version on the main page is 1.2.0. Thanks for you help!

Comment: which IE is it? for me it works well

Comment: It is IE 11 on windows 8. It is only occurring in my angular app, it works well for me on textAngular.com.

Comment: Try to post some code. I use in my angular app and it is fine in IE11 on Win8 too

Answer (score 0):

I tested your solution on IE 8,9,10 & 11 without any issues. I did however notice it the page was not formatting correctly no IE. It could be an issue with escape characters.

If you could provide some more details about your system, for example: IE version, the code you tried to paste etc. I think I may be able to sort this one out.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to work on a plunker version to see if I can replicate the behavior.

Comment: I created a plunk that replicates the problem, at least on my machine. I think this is just a bug within the library, as none of the code on that demo is my own. It is all from the github repo.

Comment: Thought I'd just drop by - for 1.2.2 there is an issue here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/298 with a workaround that has been fixed in the 1.3.0 pre-releases.